# lambda expression in entity framework including relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

i am trying to find all the friends of a user lets imagine the two tables

Users(UserID , Name)
FriendShips(id,CreatorID,FriendID,Accepted)
CreatorID and FriendID are foreign key of Users table

the query below should return all the users that are "Friends" with the User with UserID= 1;
but its returning something else

```
Int64 userID =1; 
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.FriendShips.All(y => y.Accepted == true && y.CreatorID == userID)).ToList();
```

---

if someone can tell me what should the query be using the lambda expression i will be grateful.

Comment: Try using something like:

`ctx.Users.Select(x => x.Frienships).Where(y => y.Accepted == true && y.CreatorID == userID)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try flipping the query around

```
ctx.Friendships.Where(y=>y.CreatorID==userID && y.Accepted==true).Select(y=>y.User).Distinct();
```

If FriendShips have many Users, the query would be

```
ctx.Friendships.Where(y=>y.CreatorID==userID && y.Accepted==true).SelectMany(y=>y.Users).Distinct();
```

Comment: really it works :) 
but using select user1 instead of user 
also how i can start with friend ship and return users can you explain please

Comment: and how i can get friends of friends

Comment: I would need to see your EF Diagram to understand what User1 Maps to

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns users whose **all** friends have the specific id. I don't think this is your intention. Instead, you'd like users whose **any** friend has the specific id (and has other friends possibly).